# How to Solve Django Error Message : TemplateDoesNotExist at

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates, django-urls, template-specialization

I am trying to do a project for a blog by django 3.1.2 , but unable to link the templates.I tried fixing it with `**'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),]`** I cannot find the logic miss. The template does exist and when I review the code, the query is performing correctly. I'm at a loss.

**my setting**

```
 TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'templates'),
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

**my blog urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path,include

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('posts.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

**my posts urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views


urlpatterns = [
  path('', views.home, name='home'),
]
```

**my posts views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

# Create your views here.
def home(request):
    return render(request,'posts/index.html')
```

Comment: Where is the template? What is the error message? We only see that there is a `templates` directory but not what is inside.

Comment: I tried fixing it with **'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),]**

Comment: Is index.html file exist on path `templates/posts/index.html`

Comment: TemplateDoesNotExist at /posts/index.html
Exception Location:  C:\Users\USER\Envs\projects\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py, line 19, in get_template

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your templates folder is in your application's directory
eg: app_name / templates / app_name /.html, then you do not need to add
'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),]'.

So, if your application name is my_posts, create a folder named templates in your application directory. Then again create a folder named my_posts(same as application name) in templates directory, and then inside it create all your html files. But remember in your views.py when you are rendering, you have to do it as such, 'my_posts/index.html'

You only need to add 'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),]' , if you have you template folder in your main/project directory.

Comment: My application name is posts, create a folder named templates in my posts application directory. Then again create a folder named posts(same as application name) in templates directory, and then inside it create all your html files. and setting 'DIRS': [ ]'. but show TemplateDoesNotExist at / posts/index.html

Comment: my setting files



TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]